# Datatable stuck on "proccessing" - ajax loaded

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatable

I am using an ajax handler to fetch the data I need to fill the table. My code for the table is as follows:

```
 $(function() {
        let table;

        table = $('#table_preview').DataTable({
          "processing": true,
          "serverSide": true,
          "columns": [
            { "data": "crop" },
            { "data": "diseases" },
            { "data": "chemical" },
            { "data": "product" },
            { "data": "rate" },
            { "data": "max_no" },
            { "data": "hi" },
            { "data": "mrl" },
            { "data": "pcs_no" },
            { "data": "supplier" }
          ],
          "ajax": {
            "url": "/assets/ajax/table_ajax_handler.php",
            "type": "POST",
            "data": {
              action: 'getPesticidesForTable'
            },
            "success": function(res) {
              console.log(res);
            }
          }
        });
    });
```

I have tried to get rid of the "success" in case that overrides something but it just gives me an error
When the data is console logged it looks like this

```
{
        "data": [
          {
            "crop": "Wheat",
            "diseases": "aids",
            "chemical": "Water",
            "product": "Dip dabs",
            "rate": 7,
            "max_no": 10,
            "hi": 9,
            "mrl": 45,
            "pcs_no": 1234,
            "supplier": "Me"
          }
        ]
      }
```

Comment: `success` is not a DataTables option, so it will be ignored. It is one of jQuery's `ajax` settings - but you are not using it in the `ajax` section of your DataTable, here. And as uingtea mentions, you [must not use `success`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) in your DataTables ajax call.

Comment: What error message do you get in the console, when you are stuck on "processing"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `success` callback is used by dataTable so you need to remove the following lines

```
"success": function(res) {
              console.log(res);
            }
```

don't forget to add row title `<thead><tr><th>crop</th>....` because it not added by dataTable